# How to Get selected folder name in java using JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I want to select the folder that is selected.

```
 JFileChooser targetDir = new JFileChooser();
            targetDir.setDialogTitle("Choose Target Directory.");
            targetDir.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            if(targetDir.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)   
            {
                System.out.println(targetDir.getCurrentDirectory());
                main_mw = new MainWindow("XYZ Copier");
            main_mw.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } else {
        }
```

It gives the output "/home/rahul/Downloads/mc"
but I need "/home/rahul/Downloads/mc/lib". It gives same result if i go inside lib.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: getSelectedFile will give you the directory the user selected

Comment: One step closer to world domination ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JFileChooser#getSelectedFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile()) will return the selected file/directory

`getCurrentDirctory` returns the directory which is currently been shown in the chooser